# NLTK tokenize - faster way?

Tags: python, time-complexity, nltk, tokenize, frequency

I have a method that takes in a String parameter, and uses NLTK to break the String down to sentences, then into words. Afterwards, it converts each word into lowercase, and finally creates a dictionary of the frequency of each word.

```
import nltk
from collections import Counter

def freq(string):
    f = Counter()
    sentence_list = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(string)
    for sentence in sentence_list:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
        words = [word.lower() for word in words]
        for word in words:
            f[word] += 1
    return f
```

I'm supposed to optimize the above code further to result in faster preprocessing time, and am unsure how to do so. The return value should obviously be exactly the same as the above, so I'm expected to use nltk though not explicitly required to do so.

Any way to speed up the above code? Thanks.

Comment: Questions about improving working code are generally considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. You might get help over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh, OK. Good to know. I'll try asking there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "this question belongs on another site in SE network" http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @lenz [Questions about performance are on-topic on either site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review). And SO tends to give a higher-quality answer.

Answer (score 21):

If you just want a flat list of tokens, note that `word_tokenize` would call `sent_tokenize` implicitly, see [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py#L98](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py#L98)

```
_treebank_word_tokenize = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize
def word_tokenize(text, language='english'):
    """
    Return a tokenized copy of *text*,
    using NLTK's recommended word tokenizer
    (currently :class:`.TreebankWordTokenizer`
    along with :class:`.PunktSentenceTokenizer`
    for the specified language).
    :param text: text to split into sentences
    :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus
    """
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
            for token in _treebank_word_tokenize(sent)]
```

Using brown corpus as an example, with `Counter(word_tokenize(string_corpus))`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> string_corpus = brown.raw() # Plaintext, str type.
>>> start = time.time(); fdist = Counter(word_tokenize(string_corpus)); end = time.time() - start
>>> end
12.662328958511353
>>> fdist.most_common(5)
[(u',', 116672), (u'/', 89031), (u'the/at', 62288), (u'.', 60646), (u'./', 48812)]
>>> sum(fdist.values())
1423314
```

~1.4 million words took 12 secs (without saving the tokenized corpus) on my machine with specs:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 1600.027
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2

$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       12004468 kB
```

Saving the tokenized corpus first `tokenized_corpus = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(string_corpus)]`, then using `Counter(chain*(tokenized_corpus))`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> start = time.time(); tokenized_corpus = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(string_corpus)]; fdist = Counter(chain(*tokenized_corpus)); end = time.time() - start
>>> end
16.421464920043945
```

Using `ToktokTokenizer()`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import time
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.tokenize import ToktokTokenizer
>>> toktok = ToktokTokenizer()
>>> string_corpus = brown.raw()

>>> start = time.time(); tokenized_corpus = [toktok.tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(string_corpus)]; fdist = Counter(chain(*tokenized_corpus)); end = time.time() - start 
>>> end
10.00472116470337
```

Using `MosesTokenizer()`:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesTokenizer
>>> moses = MosesTokenizer()
>>> start = time.time(); tokenized_corpus = [moses.tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(string_corpus)]; fdist = Counter(chain(*tokenized_corpus)); end = time.time() - start 
>>> end
30.783339023590088
>>> start = time.time(); tokenized_corpus = [moses.tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(string_corpus)]; fdist = Counter(chain(*tokenized_corpus)); end = time.time() - start 
>>> end
30.559681177139282
```

**Why use `MosesTokenizer`**

It was implemented in such a way that there is a way to reverse the tokens back to string, i.e. "detokenize".

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesTokenizer, MosesDetokenizer
>>> t, d = MosesTokenizer(), MosesDetokenizer()
>>> sent = "This ain't funny. It's actually hillarious, yet double Ls. | [] < > [ ] & You're gonna shake it off? Don't?"
>>> expected_tokens = [u'This', u'ain', u'&apos;t', u'funny.', u'It', u'&apos;s', u'actually', u'hillarious', u',', u'yet', u'double', u'Ls.', u'&#124;', u'&#91;', u'&#93;', u'&lt;', u'&gt;', u'&#91;', u'&#93;', u'&amp;', u'You', u'&apos;re', u'gonna', u'shake', u'it', u'off', u'?', u'Don', u'&apos;t', u'?']
>>> expected_detokens = "This ain't funny. It's actually hillarious, yet double Ls. | [] < > [] & You're gonna shake it off? Don't?"
>>> tokens = t.tokenize(sent)
>>> tokens == expected_tokens
True
>>> detokens = d.detokenize(tokens)
>>> " ".join(detokens) == expected_detokens
True
```

Using `ReppTokenizer()`:

```
>>> repp = ReppTokenizer('/home/alvas/repp')
>>> start = time.time(); sentences = sent_tokenize(string_corpus); tokenized_corpus = repp.tokenize_sents(sentences); fdist = Counter(chain(*tokenized_corpus)); end = time.time() - start
>>> end
76.44129395484924
```

**Why use `ReppTokenizer`?**

It returns offset of the tokens from in the original string.

```
>>> sents = ['Tokenization is widely regarded as a solved problem due to the high accuracy that rulebased tokenizers achieve.' ,
... 'But rule-based tokenizers are hard to maintain and their rules language specific.' ,
... 'We evaluated our method on three languages and obtained error rates of 0.27% (English), 0.35% (Dutch) and 0.76% (Italian) for our best models.'
... ]
>>> tokenizer = ReppTokenizer('/home/alvas/repp/') # doctest: +SKIP
>>> for sent in sents:                             # doctest: +SKIP
...     tokenizer.tokenize(sent)                   # doctest: +SKIP
... 
(u'Tokenization', u'is', u'widely', u'regarded', u'as', u'a', u'solved', u'problem', u'due', u'to', u'the', u'high', u'accuracy', u'that', u'rulebased', u'tokenizers', u'achieve', u'.')
(u'But', u'rule-based', u'tokenizers', u'are', u'hard', u'to', u'maintain', u'and', u'their', u'rules', u'language', u'specific', u'.')
(u'We', u'evaluated', u'our', u'method', u'on', u'three', u'languages', u'and', u'obtained', u'error', u'rates', u'of', u'0.27', u'%', u'(', u'English', u')', u',', u'0.35', u'%', u'(', u'Dutch', u')', u'and', u'0.76', u'%', u'(', u'Italian', u')', u'for', u'our', u'best', u'models', u'.')
>>> for sent in tokenizer.tokenize_sents(sents): 
...     print sent                               
... 
(u'Tokenization', u'is', u'widely', u'regarded', u'as', u'a', u'solved', u'problem', u'due', u'to', u'the', u'high', u'accuracy', u'that', u'rulebased', u'tokenizers', u'achieve', u'.')
(u'But', u'rule-based', u'tokenizers', u'are', u'hard', u'to', u'maintain', u'and', u'their', u'rules', u'language', u'specific', u'.')
(u'We', u'evaluated', u'our', u'method', u'on', u'three', u'languages', u'and', u'obtained', u'error', u'rates', u'of', u'0.27', u'%', u'(', u'English', u')', u',', u'0.35', u'%', u'(', u'Dutch', u')', u'and', u'0.76', u'%', u'(', u'Italian', u')', u'for', u'our', u'best', u'models', u'.')
>>> for sent in tokenizer.tokenize_sents(sents, keep_token_positions=True): 
...     print sent
... 
[(u'Tokenization', 0, 12), (u'is', 13, 15), (u'widely', 16, 22), (u'regarded', 23, 31), (u'as', 32, 34), (u'a', 35, 36), (u'solved', 37, 43), (u'problem', 44, 51), (u'due', 52, 55), (u'to', 56, 58), (u'the', 59, 62), (u'high', 63, 67), (u'accuracy', 68, 76), (u'that', 77, 81), (u'rulebased', 82, 91), (u'tokenizers', 92, 102), (u'achieve', 103, 110), (u'.', 110, 111)]
[(u'But', 0, 3), (u'rule-based', 4, 14), (u'tokenizers', 15, 25), (u'are', 26, 29), (u'hard', 30, 34), (u'to', 35, 37), (u'maintain', 38, 46), (u'and', 47, 50), (u'their', 51, 56), (u'rules', 57, 62), (u'language', 63, 71), (u'specific', 72, 80), (u'.', 80, 81)]
[(u'We', 0, 2), (u'evaluated', 3, 12), (u'our', 13, 16), (u'method', 17, 23), (u'on', 24, 26), (u'three', 27, 32), (u'languages', 33, 42), (u'and', 43, 46), (u'obtained', 47, 55), (u'error', 56, 61), (u'rates', 62, 67), (u'of', 68, 70), (u'0.27', 71, 75), (u'%', 75, 76), (u'(', 77, 78), (u'English', 78, 85), (u')', 85, 86), (u',', 86, 87), (u'0.35', 88, 92), (u'%', 92, 93), (u'(', 94, 95), (u'Dutch', 95, 100), (u')', 100, 101), (u'and', 102, 105), (u'0.76', 106, 110), (u'%', 110, 111), (u'(', 112, 113), (u'Italian', 113, 120), (u')', 120, 121), (u'for', 122, 125), (u'our', 126, 129), (u'best', 130, 134), (u'models', 135, 141), (u'.', 141, 142)]
```

---

**TL;DR**

**Advantages of different tokenizers**

- `word_tokenize()` implicitly calls `sent_tokenize()`
- `ToktokTokenizer()` is fastest
- `MosesTokenizer()` is able to detokenize text
- `ReppTokenizer()` is able to provide token offsets

**Q: Is there a fast tokenizer that can detokenizer and also provides me with offsets and also do sentence tokenization in NLTK ?**

A: I don't think so, try `gensim` or `spacy`.

Comment: Is it possible to just return sentence tokens instead of word tokens with toktok? That is, instead of word tokens? And would it still be faster than sent_tokenize()? I can test the latter. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the MosesTokenizer has been moved to https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses/tree/master/sacremoses

Answer (score 11):

## Unnecessary list creation is evil

Your code is implicitly [creating a lot of potentially very long `list` instances](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list) which don't need to be there, for example:

```
words = [word.lower() for word in words]
```

Using the `[...]` syntax for [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) creates a list of length *n* for *n* tokens found in your input, but all you want to do is get the frequency of each token, not actually store them:

```
f[word] += 1
```

Therefore, you should use a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/1391325) instead:

```
words = (word.lower() for word in words)
```

Similarly, [`nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize` and `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) both seem to produce lists as output, which is again unnecessary; Try to use a more low-level function, e.g. `nltk.tokenize.api.StringTokenizer.span_tokenize`, which merely generates an iterator that yields token offsets for your input stream, i.e. pairs of indices of your input string representing each token.

### A better solution

Here is an example using no intermediate lists:

```
def freq(string):
    '''
    @param string: The string to get token counts for. Note that this should already have been normalized if you wish it to be so.
    @return: A new Counter instance representing the frequency of each token found in the input string.
    '''
    spans = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer().span_tokenize(string)   
    # Yield the relevant slice of the input string representing each individual token in the sequence
    tokens = (string[begin : end] for (begin, end) in spans)
    return Counter(tokens)
```

**Disclaimer:** I've not profiled this, so it's possible that e.g. the NLTK people have made `word_tokenize` blazingly fast but neglected `span_tokenize`; Always profile your application to be sure.

### TL;DR

Don't use lists when generators will suffice: Every time you create a list just to throw it away after using it once, God kills a kitten.

Comment: Actually `word.lower()` within the list comprehension is not a good advice. The user should have lowered the input string from the start. I.e. `sent_tokenize(string.lower())`. Then there's no need to call `str.lower()`  that many times but `str.lower()` should be fast enough to see no effect in slowing down the code given that the list is not really really humonguous =)

Comment: Regardless, creating a list of any size is needless overhead; My answer has **nothing** to do with the performance of `str.lower()`.

Comment: I understand but actually creating the tokenized sentence is rather important for other NLP uses later, e.g. calculating TF-IDF, where you need both the document and sentence structure; e.g. running a sentence level classifier, topic model, etc.

Comment: What you wrote has nothing to do with the OP's requirements, which seem to be set by someone other than themselves: *I'm supposed to **optimize the above code further** to result in faster preprocessing time, and am unsure how to do so. The return value should obviously be exactly the same as the above, so I'm expected to use nltk though not explicitly required to do so* -- mention of e.g. "calculating TF-IDF" is nowhere to be found, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above tokenizers, `wordpunct_tokenize` did the job for me. This is particularly for text similarity task. I replaced `jieba.lcut(s)` with this function for better speed yet same accuracy.

```
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
s = '''Good muffins cost $3.88\nin New York.  Please buy me two of them.\n\nThanks.'''
>>> wordpunct_tokenize(s)
>>> ['Good', 'muffins', 'cost', '$', '3', '.', '88', 'in', 'New', 'York', '.',
    'Please', 'buy', 'me', 'two', 'of', 'them', '.', 'Thanks', '.']
```

[Link](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html) for the documentation.